# Can I use a letsencrypt certificate to secure macOS High Sierra Server Open Directory?

Tags: osx-server, certificate

I have services (mail, web) on macOS High Sierra Server protected with a letsencrypt certificate and that works fine. I'd like to extend that use of letsencrypt to Open Directory, to fully get rid of all that self-signed stuff. But when I select my letsencrypt cert for OD, the clients won't work with it presenting me with a "2100" error.

Now, my certificate is for `serverhost.mydomain.tld` and the server is configured as `serverhost.mydomain.tld`. DNS and all that is correct.

Information on the web about 3rd party certs is generally at least 4 years old (and not helpful). So, I'm asking a fresh question here. What steps do I have to take to have OD use my letsencrypt cert in a way that it also works on clients?